# XPATH and text of the elements are constantly updating, what is the best way to identify an element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is the XPath for element x the first time a page loads:

```
.//*[@id='001g000000YJnpR_00Nb0000004Lzej_body']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

text on this page is: "text1".

Here is the XPath for same element x the second time it loads:

```
//*[@id="001g000000YJnm8_00Nb0000004Lzej_body"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

text on this page is: "text2".

Element doesn't have a name or id and here is the HTML code:
    
        <kbd>'<'td class="dataCell">vxgkVwD7JvnOBKaGCIS7'<'/td'>'</kbd>

Please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about checking for the `id` attribute to contain `body` string using `contains()`:

```
//*[contains(@id, "body")]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

Though, posting the complete HTML code of the table could help to provide you with a more reliable and readable XPath expression.

Comment: That was quick and very stable solution, just tested it and works as expected. Thank you.